# Translate Wordpress Automatically from Multiple languages to English

Tags: wordpress, automation, translation, google-translate, wpallimport

There are a lot of plugins to translate Wordpress from e.g. English into German/French/Spanish etc.

But i am looking to achieve the opposite, i want to gather some international content and translate it automatically to English. Content will be added through WP All Import or through other import.
I will have the "international language code" per content available, so i could indicate the source language of the content.

I have reached out to several WP translation plugin developers, but they told me the plugin only work from one language to multiple others and not the other way around.

What would be the best way to get my Multilanguage content to English? I was thinking following options:

1. Have a custom extension to WPAI developed that translates on import, but the downside is that it is slow with higher volumes.
2. Perhaps it would be possible to have the content translated to English (if not available) when the page actually loads, and store the result in a column for future usage.

I don't know if above would be even possible, perhaps someone has some pointers on where i can search to find a solution for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Loco translate plugin ? I know this looks like to be the opposite of what you are trying to do but this extension lets you select what theme, plugin and even specific strings you want to automaticaly translate. You can also add configuration files to translate anything on your website as you want.

Comment: And so you can select the base language and from it, translate the rest to this one

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand correctly. You will have content in languages X, Y, Z (post in X, another post in Y, another in Z) and you want to separately translate each to English (E) like this?

```
X -> E
Y -> E
Z -> E
```

Or are you looking to somehow merge all the source languages into one (`X,Y,Z -> E`)?

If option 2 I have no idea how this would be done.

If option 1 then IMHO it doesn't matter from what and to what you want to translate. The question you need to answer is:

Which plugin(s) is(are) capable of automatically translating from all your source languages into English? For example here's a list of supported languages for WPML: https://ate.wpml.org/mt_langs

Once you import all the content into WordPress with the correct language codes which the translation plugin can recognize (to correctly perform machine translation), you will be able to translate each post/page into English using that plugin.

Comment: X -> E, 
Y -> E, 
Z -> E . But the thing i want to do it automatically.  I can store source international language code in a custom field. Then translate based on that custom field value  to English. And if possible I want to actually store the translation for future usage.

Comment: I'm not sure that you could do that without coding a custom solution. Find a translation plugin that has a decent API for automating things, write custom code to bring you content into WordPress via this API, then use the plugin capabilities to perform automatic translation of the content.

Comment: I think i will look for a custom solution, thanks for the suggestions.